# How to avoid sort operator in index plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables [LogTable] and [LogTable_Cross].

Below is the schema and script to populate them:

```
 --Main Table

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogTable]
    (
      [LogID] [int] NOT NULL
                    IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [DateSent] [datetime] NULL,
    )
 ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_LogTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([LogID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LogTable_DateSent] ON [dbo].[LogTable] ([DateSent] DESC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LogTable_DateSent_LogID] ON [dbo].[LogTable] ([DateSent] DESC) INCLUDE ([LogID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


--Cross table

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogTable_Cross]
    (
      [LogID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [UserID] [int] NOT NULL
    )
 ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogTable_Cross] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LogTable_Cross_LogTable] FOREIGN KEY ([LogID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LogTable] ([LogID])
GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LogTable_Cross_UserID_LogID]
 ON [dbo].[LogTable_Cross] ([UserID])
 INCLUDE ([LogID])
GO


-- Script to populate them
 INSERT INTO [LogTable]
        SELECT TOP 100000
                DATEADD(day, ( ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 65530 ), 0)
        FROM    sys.sysobjects
                CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns


 INSERT INTO [LogTable_Cross]
        SELECT  [LogID] ,
                1
        FROM    [LogTable]
        ORDER BY NEWID()

 INSERT INTO [LogTable_Cross]
        SELECT  [LogID] ,
                2
        FROM    [LogTable]
        ORDER BY NEWID()

 INSERT INTO [LogTable_Cross]
        SELECT  [LogID] ,
                3
        FROM    [LogTable]
        ORDER BY NEWID()


GO
```

I want to select all those logs (from LogTable) which has given userid (user id will be checked from cross table LogTable_Cross).

I have tried the following 4 different queries to do that:

```
 SELECT DMT.LogID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC ) AS RowNumber
 FROM   LogTable DMT
 WHERE  LogID IN ( SELECT   LogID
                   FROM     LogTable_Cross DMTP
                   WHERE    DMTP.UserID = 1 )

 SELECT DMT.LogID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC ) AS RowNumber
 FROM   LogTable DMT
 WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT LogID
                 FROM   LogTable_Cross DMTP
                 WHERE  DMTP.LogID = DMT.LogID
                        AND DMTP.UserID = 1 )


 SELECT DMT.LogID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC ) AS RowNumber
 FROM   LogTable DMT
        JOIN ( SELECT   LogID
               FROM     LogTable_Cross DMTP
               WHERE    DMTP.UserID = 1
             ) T ON DMT.LogID = T.LogID                            


 SELECT DMT.LogID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC ) AS RowNumber
 FROM   LogTable DMT
        INNER JOIN LogTable_Cross DMTP ON DMTP.LogID = DMT.LogID
 WHERE  DMTP.UserID = 1
```

The issue I am facing is that despite of the non clustered index I have applied of LogTable for DateSent desc it is not being used for my queries.
A heavy "Sort" operator is coming in the execution plan.

Below is the screenshot for the plan:

[image]

Can you help me fixing the queries or adding some new index so that I can avoid that "Sort" operator coming in plan?

Edit:

Even if I remove Row_Number() the sort operator is still coming for the following query:

```
 SELECT DMT.LogID  
 FROM   LogTable DMT
 WHERE  LogID IN ( SELECT   LogID
                   FROM     LogTable_Cross DMTP
                   WHERE    DMTP.UserID = 1 )
ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC
```

Here is the execution plan for this query:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using this ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC ) statement. This row_number generation requires a sort operation.

Comment: Row_Number has been populated based on some order either asc or desc. In your case "datesent" Desc. You cannot avoid sort operation in your SQL.

Comment: *Something* has to be the heaviest operator in a query plan. Maybe its not so much that there's a "heavy" sort operator, just that the rest of the plan is "light". Is this actually causing you a performance issue? On my (not particularly powerful) machine, the query completes in 2 seconds.

Comment: I wonder why the non clustered index IX_LogTable_DateSent  is not being applied for sort.

Comment: `IX_LogTable_DateSent` is superfluous as `IX_LogTable_DateSent_LogID` already indexes on DateSent and is better as it includes `LogID`.

Comment: hey @raj you can see below my answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid sort operation in your execution plan until you remove the row_number() (window function) since it requires an order either asc or desc.

In your case you are generating the row numbers based on the Datesent column order by desc so it requires a sort.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC ) AS RowNumber
```

If you want to remove sort operation from your execution plan get rid off the rownumber column from your SQL.

or else you can try like this

```
SELECT DMT.LogID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS RowNumber
 FROM   LogTable DMT
 WHERE  LogID IN ( SELECT   LogID
                   FROM     LogTable_Cross DMTP
                   WHERE    DMTP.UserID = 1 )
```

In this case sort operation will be removed but the row numbers are generated not based on any specific order. however we removed sort operator from the plan and this is what you expected.

Comment: Pleaser check my edit. I have removed Row_Number(). The sort operator is still coming.

Comment: When you put order by then you can see sort operator in your execution plan. Please remove this statement 'ORDER BY DMT.DateSent DESC' and then try

Comment: I want the rows to be ordered DateSent DESC

Comment: Then you cannot avoid sort operator in Execution Plan

Comment: hey @NewUser i think we can avoid sort iterator in some particular situations and above question is one of them.

Comment: Can you tell me that situation so that I can learn from you. Share me any link to know about it.

Comment: Thanks @NewUser you can look my answer below

Answer (score 0):

My choice:

```
CREATE UNIQUE /* !!! */ NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_LogTable_DateSent_LogID
    ON dbo.LogTable (LogID)
    INCLUDE (DateSent) --WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE /* !!! */ NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_LogTable_Cross_LogID
    ON dbo.LogTable_Cross (LogID)
    WHERE UserID = 1 --WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)
GO

SELECT t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID = 1
            AND c.LogID = t.LogID
    )
--OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Execution plan:

[image]

Bad idea:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.LogTable_Cross
    ADD DateSent DATETIME
GO

UPDATE i
SET DateSent = t.DateSent
FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross i
JOIN dbo.LogTable t ON i.LogID = t.LogID
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_IU_DataSent
    ON dbo.LogTable_Cross
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable_Cross (LogID, UserID, DateSent) 
    SELECT i.LogID, i.UserID, t.DateSent
    FROM INSERTED i
    JOIN dbo.LogTable t ON i.LogID = t.LogID

END
GO

CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.LogTable_Cross (DateSent, LogID) WHERE UserID = 1
    --WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)
GO

SELECT LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross
WHERE UserID = 1
```

Execution plan:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Agree** with @raj(OP)  that sort iterator could have  avoided to produce result with the Row Number but for that particular data I would love to have indexes below :

```
CREATE  UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  IX_DateSent_LogID  on  LogTable (DateSent  ,LogID )
CREATE UNIQUE  NONCLUSTERED INDEX  LogTable_Cross ON LogTable_Cross (UserID , LogID)
```

Now here (pass all  data knowledge to db engine so QO can take advatages of that knowledge and produce better plan) 
        index IX_DateSent_LogID is **unique**( singleton seek ) and sorted on DateSent  ,LogID and 
        index unique and LogTable_Cross is sorted on UserID , LogID

```
    Now one can think query optimizer will not use  SORT 
    But not the case below:



SELECT DateSent , t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID in ( 1) 
            AND c.LogID = t.LogID
    )
```

**EXECUTAION PLAN 1**

[image]

We have no direct control over execution plan (for good reasons offcorse)
but one can think looping through the Logtable can be a good idea to avoid SORT
so we can use loop join hint to do that

```
SELECT DateSent , t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
WHERE t.LogID in (
        SELECT LogID
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID =  1

    )
Option (loop join)
```

**EXECUTION PLAN 2**
[image]

```
Now you can see sort iterator is gone reason is simple for every row of index *IX_datesend_logid* is looping through
in logtable_cross for every row and returning mathing key on the bases id "LOGID"
```

BUT why QO has not chosen this PLAN?

```
Reason is "SUBTREE COST"
```

With *Loop Join* "17.362" compare with "5.69605" *Merge Join* 
    but on your hardware loop join (no blocking iterator) might outperform merge join with sort iterator on warm Cache
but i am not great fan of forcing plan ,

**As** you might know that expressing logical requirement differently
    sql server might go through different code path to produce different query plan to fullfill  the requirement.

You can try the CTE version to get the data

```
 ;  WITH t as

        (
        SELECT    t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t

        )


 Select    t.LogID , T.RowNumber from t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID = 1  
            AND c.LogID = t.LogID
    )
```

**EXECUTION PLAN 3**

[image]

Now the query plan is looking in perfect shape here, NO Sort iterator in the plan with segment and sequence project iterator
is pushed back in the query plan, Seems perfect and even subtree cost 2.10024.

if still not satisfied that you can try below version because
Logid is Ever-Increasing-Unique-Clustered-Index so we can also formulate the query like below

```
    Declare @minid int , @maxid int
     SELECT @minid  = min(LogID) , @maxid  = max (logid )
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID =1  

  SELECT    t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
where LogID > =@minid and   LogID < = @maxid
```

**EXECUTION PLAN 4**

[image]

> ---

You can test performance on your machines with or without warm Cache  script below :

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON



SELECT   t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID in ( 1) 
            AND c.LogID = t.LogID
    )
    option (loop join)



    print 'loop join *****************************************************'



SELECT   t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID in ( 1) 
            AND c.LogID = t.LogID
    )




    print ' Merge join*****************************************************'

    ;   WITH t as

        (
        SELECT    t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t

        )


 Select    t.LogID , T.RowNumber from t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID  =  1 
            AND c.LogID = t.LogID
    )



    --Logid is everincring unique clustered index so we can also formulate the query like below



    print 'CTE VERSION*****************************************************'

    declare @minid int , @maxid int
     SELECT @minid  = min(LogID) , @maxid  = max (logid )
        FROM dbo.LogTable_Cross c
        WHERE c.UserID =1  

  SELECT    t.LogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.DateSent DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.LogTable t
where LogID > =@minid and   LogID < = @maxid

print 'Somthing diffrent*****************************************************'
```